# Programmatically created UIImageView and UITextViews not updating in a child UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, multithreading

Scenario:
I am creating UIImageView and UITextView programmatically depending on the size I receive from the server. The flow of execution is like this:
The storyboard has a ViewController with a UIImageView.

1. dispatch_group_async(aGroup, serialQueue, block()) - a block that fetch a template image and size data for UIImageView and UITextView from server.
2. dispatch_group_notify(aGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), blockToDisplayTemplateImage()) - block to layout the base image on top of which I want to create UIImageView and UITextView.
3. At the end of the block, I call startThreading() which uses info from server to generate UIImageView and UITextView.
   3a. At the start of startThread(), dispatch_async(serialQueue, blockToCalculateDim()) - block to calculate (x,y,width,height) of UIImageView and in the same block dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blockToCreateImageViews()) - block to create UIImageView and adding them to subviews.
   3b. Similar for the UITextViews. Both of these have TapGesture attached that open Photo Gallery and Text Editor respectively. So when the user taps on the UIImageView, it opens up the Gallery, the user selects an image, which is displayed in the UIImageView. And text typed in the editor is displayed in UITextView.

A pseudo code:

```
dispatch_group_async(aGroup, serialQueue, blockToFetchTemplateImageAndSizeData());
dispatch_group_notify(aGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), blockToDisplayTemplateImage());

func blockToDisplayTemplateImage() {
    dispatch_async(serialQueue, blockToCalcTemplate(
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blocktoDisplayTemplate());
        startThreading();
    ));
}

func startThreading() {
    dispatch_async(serialQueue, blockToCalculateDimForIV() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blockToCreateAndDisplayImageViews());
    }};
    dispatch_async(serialQueue, blockToCalculateDimForTV() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blockToCreateAndDisplayTextViews());
    }};
}
```

All of the above work fine.

QUESTION:
Now I took a View Controller in Storyboard and added a Container View in it and added the view controller mentioned above as a child.
In this case, the layout is correctly displayed but sometimes the UIImageView and/or UITextView do not appear. And when I click on UIImageView and select a photo from Gallery, it is not displayed in the UIImageView. Same for UITTextView. But I see that the image is in fact assigned and get a hex when I debug.

Any help is really appriciated. I have been at it for almost a week now.

Big thank you in advance.

Comment: `needsDisplay` or explicit wrapping the specific code that changes the UI in *dispatch_get_main_queue()*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried setNeedsDisplay. But it didn't work. I think because I am not updating my rects. I am just showing the image in the iv. I called it where the image is being set in the UIImageView in the class. Should I be calling it somewhere else?
Also, I do have the code that changes the UI wrapped in dispatch_get_main_queue() already. Basically, the tap recognizer is attached to the iv and that opens gallery.

Comment: you also can join the code in those two dispatch blocks into one inside startThreading, they both address the same queue.